# How to deploy a SOAP based web service

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, soap

I am attempting to host my SOAP based web service so that I can test how it works when other clients attempt to access it.  I can't seem to establish a connection to the Endpoint after publishing it.  I have not yet attempted to deploy this service to a tomcat or glass fish server yet, is that the only way to achieve cross machine communication or am I missing something?

Any thing will help, thanks.

Edit: code that publishes the endpoint:

```
public class WebAppPublisher {
private Endpoint endpoint;

public static void main(String[ ] args) {
    WebAppPublisher self = new WebAppPublisher();
    self.create_endpoint();
    self.configure_endpoint();
    self.publish();
}
private void create_endpoint() {
    endpoint = Endpoint.create(new LionSync());
}
private void configure_endpoint() {
    endpoint.setExecutor(new MyThreadPool());
}
private void publish() {
    int port = 8888;
    String url = "http://localhost:" + port + "/lionSync";
    endpoint.publish(url);
    System.out.println("Server published with url:\n\n\thttp://localhost:"+port+"/lionSync");
    System.out.println("\nTo generate client code run:");
    System.out.println("\twsimport -p <packageName> http://localhsot:"+port+"/lionSync?wsdl -keep");
}
```

}

Thread pool:

```
public class MyThreadPool extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
private static final int pool_size = 10;
private boolean is_paused;
private ReentrantLock pause_lock = new ReentrantLock();
private Condition unpaused = pause_lock.newCondition();

public MyThreadPool(){
   super(pool_size,        // core pool size
         pool_size,        // maximum pool size
         0L,               // keep-alive time for idle thread
         TimeUnit.SECONDS, // time unit for keep-alive setting
         new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(pool_size)); // work queue 
}

// some overrides
protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
   super.beforeExecute(t, r);
   pause_lock.lock();
   try {
      while (is_paused) unpaused.await();
   } 
   catch (InterruptedException e) { t.interrupt(); } 
   finally { pause_lock.unlock(); }
}

public void pause() {
   pause_lock.lock();
   try {
      is_paused = true;
   } 
   finally { pause_lock.unlock(); }
}

public void resume() {
   pause_lock.lock();
   try {
      is_paused = false;
      unpaused.signalAll();
   } 
   finally { pause_lock.unlock(); }
}
```

}

Comment: “I can't seem to establish a connection to the Endpoint after publishing it.” How can you tell?

Comment: @VGR after publishing the Endpoint I try wsimport -p test http://<ip-address>:<port>/testServer?wsdl -keep and I try http://<ip-address>:<port>/testServer?wsdl in the browser and both the terminal and browser just hang

Comment: Can you include the code which publishes the Endpoint in your question?

Comment: If you put `http://localhost:8888/lionSync?wsdl` into a browser that's running on the same machine where the Endpoint is published, does it connect?

Comment: yeah, it connects, but I just went ahead and turned it into a war file (easier than I remember) and just let tomcat handle it and worked like a charm, thanks for the help though